# node.js how to get client hostname by using dns

Tags: node.js, sails.js

i'm trying to get client hostname by getting their ip and then use dns.reverse to do the thing, it works, i'm getting the ip but i don't client hostname. Am i misunderstand something or is there the better way to do.

```
    queue2: function(req, res){
    var mac = req.param('mac');
    var ip = req.connection.remoteAddress;

     dns.lookup(ip,function onLookup(err, addresses){

         console.log('Address :' + addresses);

     dns.reverse(addresses, function(err, hostname){

     Q_list.query("CALL GetQueuePlay('00')", function (err, result) {
         if (err){
        return res.send(err);
        }
        console.log(result);
        console.log(addresses+ ' : ' + JSON.stringify(hostname));
        return res.view('kue/kue',{q_play_list:result});
            });
        });
    });
},
```

Comment: As far as I know you can't. Hostnames are (more or less) relative to the network they're on, and can't be seen outside that network.

Comment: @Ghostrydr Even the same local?

Comment: Do you have a local DNS server?